# accuracy of long double sqrt()

Tags: c++, double, long-integer, sqrt

I have noticed a problem with the accuracy of the long double version of sqrt(). The following code demonstrates the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cfloat>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  int count=0;
  long double s=sqrt(3L);
  std::cout.precision(21);
  std::cout << "s=" << s << ", s^2=" << s*s << std::endl;
  while( s*s<3L+LDBL_EPSILON ) {
    s+=LDBL_EPSILON;
    std::cout << s << ' ' << s*s << std::endl;
    ++count;
  }
  std::cout << "sqrt(3L) is approximately " << count << " multiples of LDBL_EPSILON away from the correct value." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running this with

```
>g++ -o sqrt sqrt.cpp && ./sqrt
```

gives

```
s=1.73205080756887719318, s^2=2.9999999999999996524
1.73205080756887719329 2.99999999999999965284
1.73205080756887719339 2.99999999999999965306
... (922 lines omitted)
1.73205080756887729347 2.99999999999999999978
1.73205080756887729357 3.00000000000000000022
sqrt(3L) is approximately 926 multiples of LDBL_EPSILON away from the correct value.
```

The regular double version of sqrt() gives the double closest to the real value.

The version of g++ I'm using is

```
>g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.4.5-8' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8)
```

Is this a known bug? Should I report this somewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two issues here: First, `3L` implicitly promotes to `double` not `long double` so even though you assign the return value to a `long double` it's still using the low precision version of `sqrt`. You'll need to `static_cast` 3 to `long double` as the argument. Secondly, only the `double` version of `sqrt` is imported into the global namespace because function overloading isn't supported in C, you have to use `std::sqrt` instead.

Thus:

`long double s=std::sqrt(static_cast<long double>(3));`

Comment: Ah, yes, that was the problem. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is the value from the 'regular' version of double sqrt() experiencing a greater granularity of rounding than the long double? This is what we would expect. It could be that this 'granular' rounding happens to be hitting close to the correct value - closer than the long double sqrt.

The way to check this would be to try multiple values and compare.

Comment: With a slight modification to the code to adjust the value of s by a factor of 1+LDBL_EPSILON or 1-LDBL_EPSILON, I have tested the accuracy of sqrt() with 2, 3, 5 and 11. In each case the double sqrt() gave the correct result and the long double sqrt() was off by a significant amount - requiring 892 multiplications by 1-LDBL_EPSILON in the case of sqrt(2L) to get the most accurate value!